# How to save memory in python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-itertools

I have some question about memory error in python3.6

```
import itertools
input_list = ['a','b','c','d']
group_to_find = list(itertools.product(input_list,input_list))
a = []
for i in range(len(group_to_find)):
    if group_to_find[i] not in a:
       a.append(group_to_find[i])
```

```
    group_to_find = list(itertools.product(input_list,input_list))
MemoryError
```

Comment: Start by not using `list()` on `itertools.product()`, especially when you are using this on larger input lists. You don't need to use a list here, nor a range.

Answer (score 5):

You are creating a list, in full, from the Cartesian product of your input list, so in addition to `input_list` you now need `len(input_list) ** 2` memory slots for all the results. You then filter that list down again to a 4th list. All in all, for N items you need memory for 2N + (N * N) references. If N is 1000, that's 1 million and 2 thousand references, for N = 1 million, you need 1 million million plus 2 million references. Etc.

Your code *doesn't need to create the `group_to_find` list, **at all***, for two reasons:

1. You could just iterate and handle each pair individually:

   ```
   a = []
   for pair in itertools.product(input_list, repeat=2):
       if pair not in a:
           a.append(pair)
   ```

   This is still going to be **slow**, because `pair not in a` has to scan the whole list to find matches. You do this `N` times, for up to `K` pairs (where K is the product of the number of unique values in `input_list`, potentially equal to N), so that's N * K time spent checking for duplicates. You could use `a = set()` to make that faster. But see point 2.
2. Your end product in `a` is the exact same list of pairs that `itertools.product()` would produce anyway, *unless* you input values are not unique. You could just make those unique first:

   ```
   a = itertools.product(set(input_list), repeat=2)
   ```

   Again, **don't put this in a list**. Iterate over it in a loop and use the pairs it produces one by one.